# How to change OpenLDAP core attributes

Tags: ldap, openldap

Specifically, I need to add `ORDERING caseIgnoreOrderingMatch` to the `givenName` and `surname` attributes. I had hoped there was some way to do this using `ldapmodify` but the following is not working for me (maybe the core schema is read only, but it's giving me a syntax error):

```
$ ldapmodify -QY EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// <<EOF
dn: cn=Subschema
changetype: modify
delete: attributetypes
attributetypes: ( 2.5.4.42 NAME ( 'givenName' 'gn' ) DESC 'RFC2256: first name
 (s) for which the entity is known by' SUP name )
-
add: attributetypes
attributetypes: ( 2.5.4.42 NAME ( 'givenName' 'gn' ) DESC 'RFC2256: first name
 (s) for which the entity is known by' SUP name ORDERING caseIgnoreOrderingMatch )
-
delete: attributetypes
attributetypes: ( 2.5.4.4 NAME ( 'sn' 'surname' ) DESC 'RFC2256: last (family)
  name(s) for which the entity is known by' SUP name )
-
add: attributetypes
attributetypes: ( 2.5.4.4 NAME ( 'sn' 'surname' ) DESC 'RFC2256: last (family)
  name(s) for which the entity is known by' SUP name ORDERING caseIgnoreOrderingMatch )
EOF

modifying entry "cn=Subschema"
ldap_modify: Invalid syntax (21)
    additional info: attributetypes: value #0 invalid per syntax
$
```

I've seen some [suggestions to edit the schema files directly](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/Polycom+Corporate+Directory) which I didn't want to do, but that (stop slapd, edit `/etc/openldap/schema/core.ldif`, restart slapd) seems to have no effect.

Any pointers to how this can be done? My LDAP knowledge is tenuous at best, so any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out; the examples I was using were geared toward a different distro with slightly different config -- I'm on Scientific Linux 6.5. Combine that with my ignorance, and no wonder it didn't work. Here is what worked:

```
ldapmodify -QY EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// <<EOF
dn: cn={1}core,cn=schema,cn=config
changetype: modify
delete: olcAttributeTypes
olcAttributeTypes: {1}( 2.5.4.4 NAME ( 'sn' 'surname' ) DESC 'RFC2256: last (f
 amily) name(s) for which the entity is known by' SUP name )
-
add: olcAttributeTypes
olcAttributeTypes: {1}( 2.5.4.4 NAME ( 'sn' 'surname' ) DESC 'RFC2256: last (f
 amily) name(s) for which the entity is known by' SUP name ORDERING caseIgnore
 OrderingMatch )
-
delete: olcAttributeTypes
olcAttributeTypes: {35}( 2.5.4.42 NAME ( 'givenName' 'gn' ) DESC 'RFC2256: fir
 st name(s) for which the entity is known by' SUP name )
-
add: olcAttributeTypes
olcAttributeTypes: {35}( 2.5.4.42 NAME ( 'givenName' 'gn' ) DESC 'RFC2256: fir
 st name(s) for which the entity is known by' SUP name ORDERING caseIgnoreOrde
 ringMatch )
EOF
```

And for direct file editing, the file path was `/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/cn=schema/cn={1}core.ldif` but using `ldapmodify` is a better method.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, you should not mess around with the standard object classes. The way you answered your own question *does* work; however, it is **WAY** better to define your own local schema with either a new structural object class (which might inherit from another) or define an auxiliary object class and add it to your nodes.

I already answered a similar question over here: [Openldap problems with adding attribute](https://serverfault.com/questions/815513/openldap-problems-with-adding-attribute/818141#818141)

You can find some cleaner ways for your problem there.