# Openldap problems with adding attribute

Tags: ldap, openldap

I'm new to serverfault but I've alredy use google and serverfault searchs but cannot find answer to my problem. I need to add new attribute in ldap called permission and be able to set privilige levels.

Found several "ways to do" but non of them working. Stuck exacly like here [add new attribute to ldap users and submit to ldap](https://serverfault.com/questions/800167/add-new-attribute-to-ldap-users-and-submit-to-ldap)

Trying

```
dn: cn=core,cn=schema,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcAttributeTypes
olcAttributeTypes: <new value>

dn: cn=core,cn=schema,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcAttributeTypes
olcAttributeTypes: ( 1.2.3.4.5.6.7 
 NAME ( 'test' 'test' ) 
 DESC 'test' 
 SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.3
 SINGLE-VALUE )
```

But in the best way I get

```
modifying entry "cn=core,cn=schema,cn=config"
ldap_modify: No such object (32)
    matched DN: cn=schema,cn=config 

ldap_modify: Invalid syntax (21)
additional info: attributetypes: value #0 normalization failed
```

or

```
ldap_add: Undefined attribute type (17)
    additional info: add: attribute type undefined
```

And I'm out of ideas how to add this attribute :/

Since I must to do this I still trying (also create new server ) and getting following results
    dn: cn=config
    changetype: add
    olcAttributeTypes: ( 2.5.4.66 NAME 'permission'
    DESC 'RFC2256: For Supermicro user'
    SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15{255} )

```
ldap_add: Object class violation (65)
additional info: no objectClass attribute
```

So adding a objectClass
    ldap_add: Object class violation (65)
    additional info: object class 'person' requires attribute 'sn'

And now what ? Of course I want that permission be a part of person objectclass as MAY but still no idea how to modify objectclass
Result of
    ldapsearch -H ldap://ldap.ogicom.net -x -s base -b "" +
    base <> with scope baseObject
    # filter: (objectclass=*)
    # requesting: +
    dn:
    structuralObjectClass: OpenLDAProotDSE
    configContext: cn=config
    namingContexts: private
    supportedControl: 2.16.840.1.113730.3.4.18
    supportedControl: 2.16.840.1.113730.3.4.2
    supportedControl: 1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.1.10.1
    supportedControl: 1.3.6.1.1.22
    supportedControl: 1.2.840.113556.1.4.319
    supportedControl: 1.2.826.0.1.3344810.2.3
    supportedControl: 1.3.6.1.1.13.2
    supportedControl: 1.3.6.1.1.13.1
    supportedControl: 1.3.6.1.1.12
    supportedExtension: 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.20037
    supportedExtension: 1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.1.11.1
    supportedExtension: 1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.1.11.3
    supportedExtension: 1.3.6.1.1.8
    supportedFeatures: 1.3.6.1.1.14
    supportedFeatures: 1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.1.5.1
    supportedFeatures: 1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.1.5.2
    supportedFeatures: 1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.1.5.3
    supportedFeatures: 1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.1.5.4
    supportedFeatures: 1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.1.5.5
    supportedLDAPVersion: 3
    supportedSASLMechanisms: DIGEST-MD5
    supportedSASLMechanisms: NTLM
    supportedSASLMechanisms: CRAM-MD5
    entryDN:
    subschemaSubentry: cn=Subschema

```
# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 2
# numEntries: 1
```

Comment: Can you check is `core` schema exists:
`ldapsearch --hostname <host>--port <port> --baseDN "cn=schema,cn=config"  --searchScope base "(objectclass=*)"` and post it?

Comment: @Slipeer After doing it I've got
    
    ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Invalid credentials (49) additional info: SASL(-13): user not found: no secret in database

Comment: Of course it was necessary to execute a command with authorization `ldapsearch --hostname <host>--port <port> -x -D <admi user dn> -W --baseDN "cn=schema,cn=config" --searchScope base "(objectclass=*)"`

Comment: Ehh my mistake - I did not think that user may be different that admin ;)
    # extended LDIF
    #
    # LDAPv3
    # base <aseDN> with scope baseObject
    # filter: cn=schema,cn=config
    # requesting: (objectclass=*) 
    #

# search result
search: 2
result: 34 Invalid DN syntax
text: invalid DN

# numResponses: 1

Comment: Strange result. Try other query: `ldapsearch -x -h <your ldap host>  -b "" -s base \* +` note - the authorization is not needed. This request will give data about available baseDN.

Comment: # extended LDIF
    #
    # LDAPv3 
    # base <> with scope baseObject
    # filter: (objectclass=*) 
    # requesting: * + 
    #

    #
   dn:
   objectClass: top
   objectClass: OpenLDAProotDSE
   structuralObjectClass: OpenLDAProotDSE
   configContext: cn=config
   namingContexts: dc=removed,dc=removed
 
   subschemaSubentry: cn=Subschema

Also additional question - how to greyed text? Maybe I misunderstanding help but it wrotes about 4 spaces to create an escaped <pre> <code> block but this dont work

Comment: Ehh and another mistake in cli - the correct result of your first command

# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <cn=schema,cn=config> with scope baseObject
# filter: (objectclass=*)
# requesting: ALL
#

# search result
search: 2
result: 32 No such object

Comment: I edited the original post

Answer (score 2):

Alright, let's clean things up a bit:

1. `ldapmodify` can both *create* and *modify* nodes within your LDAP tree. This behaviour is identified by the parameter `changetype`. So if you use `changetype: add` you try to add a new node. Obviously you would need to give that new node an object class, therefore you got the error 
   `ldap_add: Object class violation (65) additional info: no objectClass attribute` (still this operation would have been unsuccessful because the dn `cn=config` already exists).
2. You first of all need to find out, which node holds the object class (for example my node `cn={0}core,cn=schema,cn=config` holds the object class 'person', whereas 'inetOrgPerson' lies in `cn={3}inetorgperson,cn=schema,cn=config`). The curly brackets in front of the first dn attribute (in this case 'core' or 'inetorgperson') are set by OpenLDAP in order to determine the order in which the nodes are loaded. BTW: that's the reason why you received `ldap_modify: No such object (32)` when looking for cn=core,... - you missed the brackets :)
3. Object classes and attribute types are stored in nodes with the object class of `olcSchemaConfig` as attributes with the attribute type of `olcObjectClasses` or `olcAttributeTypes` respectively. Just look at your schemes (e.g. `ldapsearch -xLLLWD cn=admin,cn=config -b cn=schema,cn=config -s one` or `ldapsearch -xLLLWD cn=admin,cn=config -b cn={0}core,cn=schema,cn=config -s base`) and you get an idea what this looks like. So be clear what you want to do: You are trying to *modify* a node in the form that you *replace* one of the olcObjectClasses' attributes (in the form that you redefine it including your attribute type. If the attribute type has not been defined before, you would need to add it as another attribute of type `olcAttributeTypes` either in the same node or another `olcSchemaConfig`). You would do this with

`dn: cn={0}core,cn=schema,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcObjectClasses
olcObjectClasses: {4}( 2.5.6.6 NAME 'person'...`

**HOWEVER:**

You don't want to do this. Seriously, don't. It is never a good idea to mess with the preexisting classes and attributes.

Instead, there are better options, which are way cleaner and should be chosen instead:

1. The quick way: When creating the next user node, you could use a *structural* object class (e.g. 'person') and add the *auxiliary* object class 'extensibleObject' to the mix; this let's you add attributes of any existing attribute type.
2. The right way: You can easily define your own object classes. What you would want to do in this way is either create your own *structural* class (which can inherit from any other object class and be extended by your attribute) which you would then use for your node as the *only* object class, or you could also create an *auxiliary* object class which holds the attribute and which would be used as an *additional* object class.
   If you choose this way, please make sure that you use a namespace (the numbers in the definition, like '2.5.4.66') which will not conflict with the existing classes and/or attributes. This is what this would look like:

`ldapadd -xWD cn=admin,cn=config
dn: cn=<schemaName>,cn=schema,cn=config
objectClass: olcSchemaConfig
cn: <schemaName>
olcAttributeTypes: ( <your namespace>.01.01 NAME <attributeTypeName> DESC <description> EQUALITY <equalitySettings> SYNTAX <syntaxSettings> )
olcObjectClasses: ( <your namespace>.02.01 NAME <objectClassName> DESC <description> AUXILIARY MUST <attributeTypeName> )`

Learning how to handle cn=config might be a little confusing at first, but once you understand the concepts behind it, you realize it is way cooler than the way it was before. It's definitely worth learning it.

Have fun!

Comment: If you want to learn the concepts, I suggest you check out Zytrax' guide at http://zytrax.com/books/ldap/

Comment: Thansk for instruction but still got the same error - DN not available H=4 and I don't know how to handle with this and without this attribute cannot login to Supermicro IPMI by ldap :/

Answer (score -1):

Well it not my idea but I've got an aswer. I do it maunally

·         Edit config file,

```
$ vim /etc/ldap/schema/core.schema
```

·         Add attribute type,

```
attributetype ( 2.5.4.66 NAME 'permission'

        DESC 'my desc '

        SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15{255} )
```

·         add 'permission' to objectclass 'person'

```
objectclass ( 2.5.6.6 NAME 'person'

        DESC 'RFC2256: a person'

        SUP top STRUCTURAL

        MUST ( sn $ cn )

        MAY ( userPassword $ telephoneNumber $ seeAlso $ description $ permission ) )
```

·         Create core.conf file

```
$ vim /etc/ldap/core.conf
```

·         Add below line to core.conf

```
include /etc/ldap/schema/core.schema
```

·         Remove or backup old /etc/ldap/slapd.d/cn=config/cn=schema/cn={0}core.ldif file

```
$ rm /etc/ldap/slapd.d/cn=config/cn=schema/cn={0}core.ldif
```

·         Generate new /etc/ldap/slapd.d/cn=config/cn=sch

```
$ slaptest -f /etc/ldap/core.conf -F /etc/ldap/slapd.d
```